# URL Parameters are not processed when opening in MS Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, coldfusion-2016

Okay, here's a weird issue for you guy sand gals.

I'm using a window.open tag in JS to open a `.cfm` file that will open in Excel (Report), however, the appended URL variable appears to change.  It seems that the ? gets changed to an `_` and thus the browser thinks its a text file and not a web page.  Any Ideas??

```
window.open("amal_reports/rpt_change_indicator_notes.cfm?batch="+selBatch);
```

The URL should be 
`http://example.com/amal_reports/rpt_change_indicator_notes.cfm?batch=1160` but when the browser asks what do with the file it says

> rpt_change_indicator_notes_cfm_batch=1160 and wants to open a text
>   file.

If I call the report directly in the URL without the form or JS stuff the same thing happens, conversely, if I remove the URl variable (`?batch=1160`) the report opens in Excel as expected but no data is populated because the batch number is missing.

So, to summarize, the browser is changing my `.cfm` link from `js` or directly in the browser to `_cfm` and thus it won't open in Excel as expected.

Comment: any chance you're getting a redirect to the wrong URL snuck in behind you?

Comment: How would I know that?  What do you mean?  It also does the same thing in IE.  ARGH!

Comment: You should be able to open the debug console by pressing "F12" ... there should be a network tab available.  That will allow you to inspect the network traffic for  your page.

Comment: Thanks Gleep.  When I checked out that tab in the developer tools (F12) I saw an error for a missing variable.  Once I fixed that it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.  Developer tools is one of the greatest boons to web development I've seen! :)

Comment: I agree, I use it a ton for javascript error and the 'console' tab but never looked at the Network tab.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, developer error!  It looks as though checking the developers tool (F12) based upon theGleep suggestion, I found that my page was missing or couldn't find a variable.  Once that was corrected the report open as expected.